# query to get the monthly amount using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

`membertomships` table

- `membership_startdate`  (values like `2011-01-12`, `2011-03-02`)
- `membership_Enddate` (values  `2012-01-12`, `2012-03-02`)
- `membership total amount`  (values like 300.00, 400.00)
- `member_id`

`member` table

- `member_id`

Can I get the monthly amount that the member is paying, like this table:

```
member_id   monthly amount
----------------------------
1           30.00
2           40.00
3           50.00                  
4           10.00
```

I have tried this but it was giving the total amount up to the mentioned date.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH, membership_startdate, '2011-05-10') * `membership total amount` As AMOUNTGIVENDATE ,
```

Now I want the money per month.

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is for helping when you have an issue, not doing the work for you.

Comment: What exactly is the monthly amount?

Comment: is it like total amount/(total numberof days) .. like this

Comment: You should probably add something to your table that specifies if the membership is yearly, monthly, or includes the number of months in the membership, instead of having to calculate it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find an SQL function tell you the number of months between the start date and the end date
2. Take the total value and divide it by the number of months

Roughly it might look something like this...

```
     SELECT 
         member_id, 
         30*membership_total_amount/DateDiff(membership_enddate, membership_startdate) As monthly_amount
     FROM
         member
```

You will need to see what date functions mysql supports. See the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: The answer has been edited since then. In some languages 'm' denotes months in a 'datediff' function. However mysql doesn't support this. Datediff returns the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking to compute *amount per arbitrary unit of time*, right? How do you compute that (should be pretty easy to figure out)?

Here's a clue: you already have the dividend. And you already have a representation of a period of time (the start/end dates). You need to figure out the divisor. How might you do that?